# Problems displaying image in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use Qt to open a 1920x1080 window and display a 1920x1080 image.
The problem is that it only fills the top 810 lines of the
window, and the bottom is blank.  Strangely, I can scroll the remainder of the
image with the mouse wheel.  I included the important parts of the code below.
Does anyone know why Qt isn't displaying the image at full height?

```
#define DISPLAY_WIDTH                           1920
#define DISPLAY_HEIGHT                          1080
#define QIMAGE_NUM_CHANNELS                     3
QImage *myQImage = new QImage(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, QImage::Format_RGB888);

// This merely initializes the image  
for (int row = 0 ; row < DISPLAY_HEIGHT ; row+=1) {
    uchar *tmpImg = (uchar *) myQImage->scanLine(row);
    for (int col = 0 ; col < DISPLAY_WIDTH ; col++) {
        for (int c = 0 ; c < QIMAGE_NUM_CHANNELS ; c++) {
           tmpImg[(col * QIMAGE_NUM_CHANNELS) + c] = row%256;
        }
    }
}

QDialog *myQDialog = new QDialog(this);
myQDialog->setGeometry(0, 0, DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
QGraphicsScene *myGraphicsScene = new QGraphicsScene;
myGraphicsScene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*CompositeOneQImage));

QGraphicsView *myGraphicsView = new QGraphicsView(myGraphicsScene, myQDialog);
myGraphicsView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
myGraphicsView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
myQDialog->show();
```

Comment: Fixed it.  This solves it:  myGraphicsScene->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))

Comment: Can you turn your comment into an answer to your question and accept it? This way it is easily visible that your question no longer needs an answer.